# my menu material is different from most people's menus on the internet, how to replace it?

Tags: materials, interface

This is my material menu look like

[image: This is my material menu look like]

meanwhile this is most people material menu look like in most youtube tutorials https://www.wikihow.com/images/thumb/5/5a/Blender-Diffuse-and-Color.png/363px-Blender-Diffuse-and-Color.png.webp

Comment: You're using Blender 2.79 (or previous version) with "Blender Render" engine. Try to change the rendering engine to "Cycles". You will usually find that in a combo box in the top bar where you now have "Blender render" chosen.

Answer (score 1):

As @Lemon said,
change your RenderEngine to Cycles and in the MaterialTab tick "use nodes". Now you have the same menu as in the YouTubeTutorials.